# why RabbitMQ shows activity on Message rates but not on Queued messages?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have this issue, I want to know my rabbit is working great.

I am not gonna send the message, so, Im not 100% sure is being sent correctly. But the problem is this.

After all is configured and all....

I see at the RabbitMQ web manager

[image]

And when I supposedly send a message the I see activity on the "message rates" chart but nothing at the "queued messages" .

I frankly dont know whats going on, is it too fast that doesnt need to queue the messages? Or something is misconfigured?

Any idea of the difference?

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue. Response below is misleading. Actively messages are sent to my production Q and consumed by consumers properly. But still messages does not show any change where as message rate is showing activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case RabbitMQ receive non-routable message it drop it. So while message was received, it was not queued.

You may configure [Alternate Exchanges](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ae.html) to catch such messages.

Comment: thanks, and why are they non-routable? is because there is no defined queue for them or because there is no consumer?

Comment: Non-routable message are messages which are published to exchanges but have no queue to be routed to. To be sure that's your case exactly non-routable message and not something other or even RabbitMQ bug (less likely).  You may also have a look at [RabbitMQ official user group ](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users), RabbitMQ staff are active there enough.

Comment: Ive checked it... any idea how to configure an alternate exchange to catch all non-routable messages?

Comment: I don't think this is a correct answer. The charts above are from the "queue" view, and, besides, TS said: "I see activity on the "message rates""; so, if the message cannot be routed, it would not go to this queue at all, right? And it would not show up on "message rates". That's something different. I am facing the same problem right now, looks like my message is delivered and acked, but still is not shown on "queued messages".

Comment: If your message goes from exchange to queue and you do ack/nack message or they are timed out by queue length/timeout, [Dead Letter Exchanges](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) looks like a solution to catch them and then you can also grasp from message headers why it's get deadlettered.

Comment: This answer is right. Make sure the routing key exists (I.e. It is the same name as your declared queue)

Answer (score 1):

In my case,

##### Situation1:

when my `Exchange` in `rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend` **was not set properly** -- the message was not sent to the correct queue -- the `Queued messages` was **empty** all time.

however, `Message rates` is not zero, it does show there are message get sent.

Which correspond to what the other answer is saying:

> In case RabbitMQ receive non-routable message it drop it.

##### Situation2:

when my `Exchange` in `rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend` was **indeed set properly** -- the message was sent to the correct queue -- the `Queued messages` was **queuing up** the message.

Everything seems fine.

##### Situation3:

(continue from Situation2)

And now, I **turn on** the `receiver service` which has the `@RabbitListener`.

The `Queued messages` **immediately drops down to 0, and never goes up again**.

But the transporting of messages is still working fine.

[image]

##### Situation4:

(continue from Situation2)

And now, I change the `receiver service` to use the `rabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert`.

Which I **manually** `receive` the message from the `queue` every 2s by using a loop.

- (message is also `sent` from `sender service` every 2s by using a loop, same as the situations before.)

Now, the `Queued messages` **stays at constant** -- a straight line

- (depends on how many message you have queued up, in my case `1`, before the `receiver service` is up, then it stays at `1`).

[image]

##### Conclusion:

**I suspect that, when the message is consumed too fast, the `Queued messages` will just show 0.**

Which correspond to what the OP is saying:

> is it too fast that doesnt need to queue the messages?

<sub><sup>(or, I could screw up some setting in RabbitMQ and led to wrong conclusion. I dont think so, but idk, I am not familiar with RabbitMQ.)</sup></sub>